# strtok and storage in arrays: output not as expected

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, strtok

In the below code, the file test.txt has the following data :
    192.168.1.1-90
    192.168.2.2-80

The output of this is not as expected.
I expect the output to be
192.168.1.1
90
192.168.2.2
80
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char *result[10][4];
  int i=0;
  const char s[2] = "-";
  char *value,str[128];
  fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    printf("File doesn't exist\n");
  else{
    while(!feof(fp)){

      if(fgets(str,sizeof(str),fp)){

        /* get the first value */
        value = strtok(str, s);
        result[i][0]=value;
        printf("IP : %s\n",result[i][0]); //to be removed after testing


        /* get second value */
        value = strtok(NULL, s);
        result[i][1]=value;
        printf("PORT : %s\n",result[i][1]); //to be removed after testing
        i++;
     }}
    for (int k=0;k<2;k++){
        for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
            printf("\n%s\n",result[k][j]);
       }
   }

 }
        return(0);
 }
```

Comment: You have the expected output but please also add the actual (wrong) output.

Comment: The `while` loop is constantly overwriting the same `str` buffer. That's probably not what you want. And also see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: If doing POSIX, replace `strtok(str, s)` by `strdup(strtok(str, s))`. Also take care to free `result[i][x]`  if not used anymore than.

Comment: A string literal is fine for the delimiter, e.g. `const char *s = "-";` Your character array is fine as well.

Comment: OT: The common notation to describe addresses with ports is "*address:port*", note the colon.

Comment: @kaylum the actual output is :     
192.168.2.2         
80        
192.168.2.2       
80       
And the `str` , its value is being written in the array and then its being overwritten. Then how is it creating a problem.?

Comment: You are storing *pointers* to str in the array. You are not making copies of the content.

Comment: So what must I change, I'm all puzzled up in here... @kaylum

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution. It uses dynamic memory instead, but does what your after.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 128

void exit_if_null(void *ptr, const char *msg);

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    FILE *filename;
    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
    char *sequence;
    char **ipinfo;
    int str_size = 10, str_count = 0, i;

    filename = fopen("ips.txt", "r");

    if (filename == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error Reading File!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ipinfo = malloc(str_size * sizeof(*ipinfo));
    exit_if_null(ipinfo, "Initial Allocation");

    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFSIZE, filename) != NULL) {
        sequence = strtok(buffer, "-\n");

        while (sequence != NULL) {
            if (str_size == str_count) {
                str_size *= 2;
                ipinfo = realloc(ipinfo, str_size * sizeof(*ipinfo));
                exit_if_null(ipinfo, "Reallocation");
            }

            ipinfo[str_count] = malloc(strlen(sequence)+1);
            exit_if_null(ipinfo[str_count], "Initial Allocation");

            strcpy(ipinfo[str_count], sequence);

            str_count++;

            sequence = strtok(NULL, "-\n");
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < str_count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", ipinfo[i]);
        free(ipinfo[i]);
        ipinfo[i] = NULL;
    }

    free(ipinfo);
    ipinfo = NULL;

    fclose(filename);

    return 0;
}

void
exit_if_null(void *ptr, const char *msg) {
    if (!ptr) {
        printf("Unexpected null pointer: %s\n", msg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to understand is that `char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)` internally modifies the string pointed to by `str` and uses that to store the result. So the returned pointer actually points to somewhere in `str`.

In your code, the content of `str` is refreshed each time when you parse a new line in the file, but the address remains the same. So after your `while` loop, the content of `str` is the last line of the file, somehow modified by `strtok`. At this time, `result[0][0]` and `result[1][0]` both points to the same address, which equals the beginning of `str`. So you print the same thing twice in the end.

This is further illustrated in the comments added to your code.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *result[10][4];
    int i=0;
    const char s[2] = "-";
    char *value,str[128];
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("File doesn't exist\n");
    else{
        while(!feof(fp)){

            if(fgets(str,sizeof(str),fp)){

                /* get the first value */
                value = strtok(str, s);
                // ADDED: value now points to somewhere in str
                result[i][0]=value;
                // ADDED: result[i][0] points to the same address for i = 0 and 1
                printf("IP : %s\n",result[i][0]); //to be removed after testing


                /* get second value */
                value = strtok(NULL, s);
                // ADDED: value now points to somewhere in str
                result[i][1]=value;
                // ADDED: result[i][1] points to the same address for i = 0 and 1
                printf("PORT : %s\n",result[i][1]); //to be removed after testing
                i++;
            }}
        // ADDED: now result[0][0]==result[1][0], result[0][1]==result[1][1], you can test that
        for (int k=0;k<2;k++){
            for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
                printf("\n%s\n",result[k][j]);
            }
        }

    }
    return(0);
}
```

To get the expected output, you should copy the string pointed by the pointer returned by `strtok` to somewhere else each time, rather than just copy the pointer itself.